# Create grid view which contains CheckBoxes dynamically in winform application

Tags: c#

I want to create `grid view` which contains `CheckBoxes` dynamically in my winform application.

How can I perform this?

`checkBoxes` get data at runtime like the view of `E-mails`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatGridView has a default column type as CheckBoxes. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn%28VS.80%29.aspx) on how to use them.